# How to remove custom vim syntax and filetype settings for a specific

Tags: apache, vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I somehow botched the default syntax highlighting and filetype recognition for my apache httpd-vhosts.conf file, such that every time I open it in vim, the syntax and filetype are both set to "conf".  All of the other files in the ../conf.d/ directory are recognized properly, i.e. as syntax and filetype both set to "apache".  I've tried the following:

1. manually setting both in vim, i.e.

   - :set syntax=apache, :set filteype=apache
   - This works for the session, but they both reset back to "conf" when the file is reopened
2. Looking for the ~/.vimrc

   - I don't seem to have one, since I typically edit this file as root
3. yum remove and reinstall of vim

   - no change.

I know that there are a lot of posts regarding similar issues with vim syntax and filetype problems, but I cannot figure out how to resolve mine.  My guess is that there is a mapping *somewhere* that says this one particular file should be recognized as a "conf", but that's all I've got.  tia.

edit: to clarify, what I would like to know is how this one file got "stuck" on the "conf" syntax and filetype, whereas all of the other .conf files are "apache" syntax and filetype.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a modeline. Put this at the top of your file:

```
# vim: ft=apache
```

If you do not have a `.vimrc` file, you can create one. Keep in mind that each user has a separate `.vimrc` in their home folder. You can also look for the system default `vimrc` (without a dot) located in your vim installation folder. To find out where that is, type `:echo $VIM` in vim.

If you do create a new `.vimrc` for your user, you can set all `.conf` files to have apache highlighting as follows:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.conf set filetype=apache
```

Comment: adding the modeline "# vim: ft=apache" didn't have any impact.  $VIM is apparently not set at all, and unless there is somewhere else I should look other than the "~/" dir and subdirs, I don't appear to have a ".vimrc" file at all.  I have ".viminfo" file, which I have tried removing altogether with no apparent impact. (just added that attempted step to the original description).

Comment: I realize that I could create a .vimrc file and add some commands to it, but what I'd really like to know is how this one file is being treated differently when there isn't a .vimrc or any other config file pertaining to it?  How does vim know to treat the httpd-vhosts.conf file differently than the ssl.conf file (which is in the same dir)?